# How to create a message box for more than 160 rows (10836), to display text in multiple columns depending on which row is selected?

Tags: vba, excel, macros, messagebox

I'm using the code below to create a message box which displays when cells A1, A2, A3 ... until A9 are selected which will then display the text in the quotes as well as text in cells V1 (+21) , W1 (+22) and X1 (+23) for when A1 is selected for example, when A2 is selected it will display the string of text in the code below as well as text in the cells V2, W2 and X2 and so on. I need to do this for all 10836 rows but it seems as though 160 cases is the limit using this method. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Any help would be appreciated

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Column = 1 Then
Select Case Target.Row
   Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
       MsgBox "Changes : " & Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 22) & vbNewLine & " ABC Comments: " & Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 23) & vbNewLine & "XYZ Comments: " & Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 21), vbInformation, "Comments"
   Case Else:
End Select
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you use if target.row<10836 then

Comment: What @Nathan said (I did write it in full, but then realised you'd already put it).  On a side note - the `Case` statement could be shortened to `Case 1 To 9`, but you don't need the `Case` statement.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, your answers solved my problem. appreciate it.

Comment: If your problem is solved, kindly remember to accept the answer that solves it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking along the same lines as Darren Bartrup-Cook; here it is in full:

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

   Dim LastRow As Integer
   LastRow = 10836

   If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
   If Target.Column = 1 Then

    Select Case Target.Row
       Case 1 To LastRow
           MsgBox "Changes : " & Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 22) & vbNewLine & " ABC Comments: " & Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 23) & vbNewLine & "XYZ Comments: " & Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 21), vbInformation, "Comments"
       Case Else:
    End Select
    End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code was nearly there.  Rather than a case statement I would recommend using an IF statement.

```
' Event fired when the user changes the selected cells.
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Has user selected a single cell in row A, between 1 to A10836?
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row <= 10836 Then

        MsgBox "Changes: " & Cells(Target.Row, 23) & vbCrLf & _
                "ABC Comments: " & Cells(Target.Row, 24) & vbCrLf & _
                "XYZ Comments: " & Cells(Target.Row, 22) & vbCrLf
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, is this because the IF statement would require less processing on excels part? my file is getting big as it is and am trying to limit how code so that it doesnt take a long time to load. Thanks again!

Comment: Partly. Definitely agree that when it comes to code less is more. But also; IF statements are designed for simple choices. *IF Kettle.Switch = On THEN Water.Heat = True*. CASE statements work better with a range of values. *SELECT Toaster.Setting CASE SettingLow: Toaster.Heat = 25% CASE SettingMedium: Toaster.Heat = 50% CASE SettingHigh: Toaster.Heat = 100%*. In your case the choice is simple. Has the user selected an "action" cell or not.